# Ethereum net status

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I couldn't see my transactions on eth-netstats graph for my private network. Its listing out all other details like below. What am I missing, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

I am running the application in: 
 - Node: 4.6.0
 - NPM: 3.10.7

Geth command used to start the server:

```
geth --identity "nodeB" --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport "8001" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "/home/node_b" --port "30304" --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --autodag --networkid 1900 --nat "any" console
```

Comment: Its resolved. The eth-netstats was not getting data from the eth-netstats intelligent api, restarting the eth-netstats-api resolved the issue.

Comment: I have a similar issue where in i am unable to see any active node. The portal always show 0/2 Active nodes. But I got green alert message on top right saying Got Node INformation. Any help is much helpful...

Comment: Check the log of pm2 service with the command: sudo pm2 log. And see what is going wrong. Thats the first step.

Comment: Thank you very much Minisha. The rpcapi were not enabled with net,eth. Thanks again.

Comment: Still unable to see transactions though. :( Tried your way of restarting pm2 as well. No luck yet...

Comment: In the pm2 log did you find anything? does it able to gather the data from net-stats api?

Comment: Yes I can see some data being fetched..

Comment: 1|gcsnode  |      uptime: 100 } }
1|gcsnode  | 2017-01-30 17:28 +05:30: [eth] =i= { id: 'gcsnode',
1|gcsnode  |   stats: 
1|gcsnode  |    { active: true,
1|gcsnode  |      syncing: false,
1|gcsnode  |      mining: false,
1|gcsnode  |      hashrate: 0,
1|gcsnode  |      peers: 0,
1|gcsnode  |      gasPrice: '20000000000',
1|gcsnode  |      uptime: 100 } }

Comment: Did you make sure that your transaction is mined in the geth terminal.

Comment: yes i usually mine manually miner.start() after every txn being generated.

Comment: I had the same issue, but for me the transaction was not mined when I looked for pending transactions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134372/discussion-between-vny-kumar-and-minisha-murugan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its resolved. The eth-netstats was not getting data from the eth-netstats intelligent api, restarting the eth-netstats-api resolved the issue.